# How to register page views in a React / Redux app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

**Edit**

Actually, I'm fairly certain that this is because my action creator doesn't return an action and the first property of an action is supposed to be a type and that is therefore undefined...

I have a React/Redux SPA that I want to register page views on with a custom analytics engine (ie, not Google Analytics). I'm trying to register page views.

So I have attempted to do this by setting lifecycle hooks in React to fire a Redux action:

```
class ConfirmationPage extends Component {
  ...
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.registerPageVisited('confirmation');
  }
}
```

However, I receive a `Cannot read property 'type' of undefined` error presumably because I am modifying the state via the props. Looking at the stack trace, it brings me to that hook. However, I've tried other hooks such as `componentDidMount` and even `componentWillUnMount` and I get the same error.

For context, my action creator is this:

```
export function registerPageVisited(page) {
  DB.child('visits')
    .child(store.getState().visit)
    .update({ [page]: true });
}
```

where the DB is a firebase reference.

So, how should I keep track of page views?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide code where you instantiate `ConfirmationPage` component?

In the `componentWillMount` function what you are actually doing is calling `registerPageVisited` function which should be passed as props which should look something like: `<ComponentPage registerPageVisited={registerPageVisited} />`

As you are suspecting, since your `registerPageVisited` does not return action object it is not action creator. If you will make it an action creator, then you  should use [mapDispatchToProps](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) function to use it like any other props as sen in your example.

Comment: I do have a map state to dispatch function. I should have provided that as context. The problem ended up being not returning an action from the action creator.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate to this is have a different object listen to notifications from the store and update the DB based on the changes it's seeing. That will isolate any metrics collection from your view hierarchy.

You'd have to replicate some logic that determines which React components are getting shown into that object, but you could pull that into a separate class and use it in both places.

If you're using react-router, there might be hooks that fire when the active route changes. However, I haven't investigated that.

Comment: I think this is the right approach moving forward. I haven't seen much on connecting redux with a persistent store but I think that's what I will do next.  Thanks